# Pyexcel changing a cell value

Tags: python, excel, pyexcel

So I was using `openpyxl` for all my Excel projects, but now I have to work with `.xls` files, so I was forced to change library. I've chosen `pyexcel` cuz it seemed to be fairly easy and well documented. So I've gone through hell with creating hundreds of variables, cuz there is no `.index` property, or something.

What I want to do now is to read the column in the correct file, f.e "Quantity" column, and get f.e value `12` from it, then check the same column in other file, and if it is not 12, then make it 12. Easy. But I cannot find any words about changing a single cell value in their documentation. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get it, wouldn't it be the most simple thing?

```
column_name = 'Quantity'
value_to_find = 12
sheets1 = pe.get_book(file_name='Sheet1.xls')
sheets1[0].name_columns_by_row(0)
row = sheets1[0].column[column_name].index(value_to_find)

sheets2 = pe.get_book(file_name='Sheet2.xls')
sheets2[0].name_columns_by_row(0)
if sheets2[0][row, column_name] != value_to_find:
    sheets2[0][row, column_name] = value_to_find
```

## EDIT

Strange, you can only assign values if you use cell_address indexing, must be some bug. Add this function:

```
def index_to_letter(n):
    alphabet = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
    result = []
    while (n > 26):
        result.insert(0, alphabet[(n % 26)])
        n = n // 26
    result.insert(0, alphabet[n])
    return ''.join(result)
```

And modify the last part:

```
sheets2[0].name_columns_by_row(0)
col_letter = index_to_letter(sheets2[0].colnames.index(column_name))
cel_address = col_letter+str(row+1)
if sheets2[0][cel_address] != value_to_find:
    sheets2[0][cel_address] = value_to_find
```

### EDIT 2

Looks like you cannot assign only when you use the column name directly, so a around would be to find the column_name's index:

```
sheets2[0].name_columns_by_row(0)
col_index = sheets2[0].colnames.index(column_name)
if sheets2[0][row, col_index] != value_to_find:
    sheets2[0][row, col_index] = value_to_find
```

Comment: Okay, but it does not change cell value after if statement is false

Comment: You will have to save the workbook to see save changes: `sheets2.save_as('Some.xls')`. Or to replace `sheets2.save_as(sheets2.path + '/' + sheets2.filename)`

Comment: I know, still nothing

Comment: pyexcel development version v0.3.0 fixed cell addressing issue. `row = sheets1[0].column[column_name][value_to_find]` or `row = sheets1[0][value_to_find, column_name]` should return the value. And assignment in the same syntax should work too. Here's the [updated documentation](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Excel uses 2 sets of references to a cell. Cell name ("A1") and cell vector (Row, Column).

The [PyExcel documentation tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel/tutorial.html) states it supports both methods. caiohamamura's method tries to build the cell name - you don't need to if the cells are in the same location in each file, you can use the vector.

Once you have the cell, assigning a value to a single cell is simple - you assign the value. Example:

```
import pyexcel
sheet = pyexcel.get_sheet(file_name="Units.xls")
print(sheet[3,2]) # this gives me "cloud, underwater"
sheet[3,2] = "cloud, underwater, special"
sheet.save_as("Units1.xls")
```

Note that all I had to do was "sheet[3,2] =".
This is not explicitly stated but is hinted at in the [pyexcel documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyexcel/tutorial05.html) where it states that to update a whole column you do:

sheet.column["Column 2"] = [11, 12, 13]

i.e. replace a list by assigning a new list. Same logic applies to a single cell - just assign a new value.

Bonus - the [Row, column] method gets around cell locations in columns greater than 26 (i.e. 'AA' and above).

Caveat - make sure in your comparison you are comparing like-for-like i.e. int is understood to be an int and not a str. Python should implicitly converted but in some circumstances it may not - especially if you are using python 2 and Unicode is involved.